# Sentence construction with for and to

Tags: sentence-construction

1. Please refund to our customer. (This is talking about the receiver of the action, in this case the customer.)
2. Please refund for our customer. (This is talking about the reason of the action)

I am not sure I understand it right. Can the second sentence also be used to indicate the receiver of the action?

Comment: Neither of those sentences are very good as they are a bit ambiguous with the second being not understandable.  I would say: 1. Please give a refund to our customers.  - refund as a verb just feels a bit cold.  The next would express your idea better as: 2. This refund is for our customer.  Or: Please refund the money as it is for our customer.